# how to build OpenBR?

Tags: qt, opencv, visual-studio-2015, openbr

When i build OpenBR on windows and when i type following code on VS2015 x86 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt as mentioned in [A hacker's guide to building, editing, and running OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/docs/install/index.html#windows) :

```
cmake -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="H:/opencv-2.4.11/build/install;H:/Qt/Qt‌​5.8/5.8/msvc2015_6‌​4" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install" -DBR_INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

i get this error :

```
H:\openbr\build-msvc2015>cmake -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_
PATH="H:/opencv-2.4.11/build/install;H:/Qt/Qt5.8/5.8/msvc2015_64" -DC
MAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install" -DBR_INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=
Release ..
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- OpenCV ARCH: x64
-- OpenCV RUNTIME:
-- OpenCV STATIC: OFF
CMake Warning at H:/opencv-2.4.11/build-msvc2015/install/OpenCVConfig.cmake:161
(message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:88 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    H:/opencv-2.4.11/build-msvc2015/install/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/openbr/build-msvc2015/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

what's problem?

Comment: Finds some incompatible OpenCV, maybe it's built with different compiler. Try to cross-compile OpenBR on Linux with [MXE](http://mxe.cc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit OpenCVConfig.cmake file (H:/opencv-2.4.11/build-msvc2015/install/OpenCVConfig.cmake). And set OpenCV_RUNTIME to VC14:

```
elseif(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1800)
  set(OpenCV_RUNTIME vc12)
elseif(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1900)
  set(OpenCV_RUNTIME vc14)
endif()
```